# Why my <a> tag selection isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="list-group" id="generalView">
    <a href="" id="today" onclick="displayData()" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#displayDiary">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Today's Diary</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Last Week's Diaries</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Last Month's Diaries</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

```js
$('#generalView > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#generalView > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I want to add a class `active` when an `<a>` tag is clicked but my selection isn't working. Am  I selecting wrong? I already tried to give a single class to every `<a>` element and then try to select that class but doesn't work as well. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ejfxa4jL/. Note that you'll need to call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the handler function, otherwise the page will be transferred and the state will be lost. If you want to retain state between pages then you need to store the selection somewhere, eg. in the URL as a querystring parameter, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, a cookie, the server side session, or in a datastore.

Comment: You're editing the question faster than I can write an answer - at one point it was fine - there was no issue with your selectors as far as I could see. Only issue is you probably want to target `$(this)` for your `addClass` call not every `<a>` tag that's a child of `#generalView`  If you're ever in doubt about that just test them in console on the page you're unsure about - no need to use alerts :). Apologies if this is less relevant now but the edits!

Comment: That sounds so reasonable and I tried that but didn't work. The code inside isn't workin. I even tried to select only the `<a>` tags and doesn't work as well. Seems like even when I call `preventDefault()` the code just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using a class on each a tag. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#generalView > a').click(function() {
    $('.myClass').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});

});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="generalView">
    <a href="" id="today" onclick="displayData()" class="list-group-item myClass" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#displayDiary">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Today's Diary</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item myClass">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Last Week's Diaries</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item myClass">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Last Month's Diaries</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in my question I already tried that and didn't work :/ but thanks

Comment: @G.Rocha I guess I'm a little confused about your question. So lets say you click on Link 1 then this link should be the ONLY link with red color. Then if you click on Link 2 then this link should be the ONLY one with red color and so on... Is that what you want? because thats what my code does

Comment: Yes. I want to do that. The problem is that the selection isn't working so all my javascript code isn't running. So I want to know why the selection isn't working.

Comment: @G.Rocha but my code does exactly what you want. What is wrong with my code? did you test my code?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without js

consider following code for your situation

```css
a:active {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="generalView">
    <a href="" id="today" class="list-group-item myClass" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#displayDiary">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Today's Diary</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item myClass">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Last Week's Diaries</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="list-group-item myClass">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Last Month's Diaries</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```